# docker - pass arguments to the script during build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to pass argument (from the docker command) to the shell script inside the Dockerfile.

This is the docker command line.

```
docker build --file=DockerfileTest --build-arg docker_image=PX-release-migration  --tag=test-image:latest --rm=true  .
```

This is a script that is called inside the Dockerfile.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
image_name=$1
echo "docker image is $image_name"

if [[ ($image_name == '') || ($image_name == *"-dev-"*) ]]; then
    echo "This is development"
    cp src/main/resources/application-dev.properties src/main/resources/application.properties
elif [[ $image_name == *"-preprod-"* ]]; then
    echo "This is preprod"
    cp src/main/resources/application-stg.properties src/main/resources/application.properties
elif [[ $image_name == *"-release-"* ]]; then
    echo "This is production"
    cp src/main/resources/application-prod.properties src/main/resources/application.properties
fi
```

When I execute separately the script, it works, but it doe

This is docker file.

```
ARG spring_env=local
ARG docker_image=-local-

FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8
COPY . /apps/demo

WORKDIR /apps/demo

RUN chmod +x /apps/demo/initialize_env.sh
RUN ./initialize_env.sh $docker_image

RUN echo "spring_env is ${spring_env}"
```

So basically, i would like to use a different spring application properties file during the build depending on the docker_image name. If a docker image name contains 'release', i would like to package application-prod.properties during the build.

This is the error message that I am getting.

```
Step 1/8 : ARG spring_env=local
Step 2/8 : ARG docker_image=-local-
Step 3/8 : FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8
 ---> 4c81be38db66
Step 4/8 : COPY . /apps/demo
 ---> 41439197c465
Step 5/8 : WORKDIR /apps/demo
 ---> Running in 56bd408c2eb1
Removing intermediate container 56bd408c2eb1
 ---> 4c4025bf5f64
Step 6/8 : RUN chmod +x /apps/demo/initialize_env.sh
 ---> Running in 18dc3a5c1a54
Removing intermediate container 18dc3a5c1a54
 ---> 60d2037a0209
Step 7/8 : RUN ./initialize_env.sh $docker_image
 ---> Running in 2e049b2cf630
docker image is 
./initialize_env.sh: 5: ./initialize_env.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
The command '/bin/sh -c ./initialize_env.sh $docker_image' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

When I execute separately the script, it works, but it doesn't inside the docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tip:** Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check scripts for syntax errors.

> ```
> #!/bin/sh -e
> ```
>
> ```
> if [[ ($image_name == '') || ($image_name == *"-dev-"*) ]]; then
> ```

`[[` is bash syntax but your script is declared to use plain sh. It works on your machine presumably because `sh` is really symlinked to `bash`, but inside the container that's not the case. `maven:3.6.1-jdk-8` is based on `debian:stretch` which uses [dash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dash) instead of bash.

Change the shebang line. You can also delete the parentheses; they're superfluous.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

```
if [[ $image_name == '' || $image_name == *"-dev-"* ]]; then
```

You could also use a `case` block to simplify the repetitive checks.

```
case "$image_name" in
    ''|*-dev-*)
        echo "This is development"
        cp src/main/resources/application-dev.properties src/main/resources/application.properties
        ;;

    *-preprod-*)
        echo "This is preprod"
        cp src/main/resources/application-stg.properties src/main/resources/application.properties
        ;;

    *-release-*)
        echo "This is production"
        cp src/main/resources/application-prod.properties src/main/resources/application.properties
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i am getting 'this is development' for printout. it seems the 'image_name' is empty. For image_name=$,1 is this a correct syntax?

Comment: No comma. `image_name=$1`.

Comment: I think you need braces in the dockerfile: `RUN ./initialize_env.sh ${docker_image}`